# How to Route back with passing parameters using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working on Laravel 5.0. I want to return back from my current page to the previous page with passing parameter. I have an id of all images and galleries in my urls. After clicking on a particular image, i move to another page with the id of that image in my url, Now, i want to return back to my gallery page to which that image belongs to.

My controller:

```
   public function viewgallerypics($id){
        $gallery= Gallery::findorFail($id);
        return view('dropzone' , ['gallery'=>$gallery]);
         }

    public function bigimage($id){
       $gallery=Gallery::all();
       $image=image::findorFail($id);
       return view('bigimage' , ['image'=>$image,'gallery'=>$gallery]);

       }
```

My routes:

```
       Route::get('/image/big/{id}' ,[
       'uses'=>'GalleryController@bigimage',
       'as'=>'bigimage'
       ]);


       Route::get('/gallery/view/{id}' ,[
       'uses'=>'GalleryController@viewgallerypics',
       'as'=>'viewpics'
       ]);
```

My view:

```
    <section class="col-md-1">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
    href="HERE, WHAT I HAVE TO PASS TO GET MY DESIRED
    PAGE????">Back</a>
    </section>
```

My desired page where i want to return back depending on the id pass through the route:

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
 <div  id="gallery-images">
 <ul>
 @foreach($gallery->images as $image)
 <li>
 <a href="{{ URL('/image/big/'.$image->id) }}">
 <img id="jumboimage2" src="{{   url($image->file_path) }}"></a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a href="{{ URL('/image/delete/'.$image->id) }}" id="margin">
 <span id="margin" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></a>
 </li>
 @endforeach
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: you want to return to previous page or you gallery that image belongs to

Comment: on the page from where i am clicking on the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `{{ URL::previous() }}`

```
<section class="col-md-1">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{{ URL::previous() }}">Back</a>
</section>
```